# Using TextField hides the ScrollView beneath it in VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, user-input, textfield, swiftui-navigationview

This view hold a list of pdf names which when tapped open webviews of pdf links.

The view has a search bar above the list which when tapped causes the scrollview to disappear.

```swift
struct AllPdfListView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    @ObservedObject var pdfsFetcher = PDFsFetcher()
    
    @State var searchString = ""
    
    @State var backButtonHidden: Bool = false
    
    @State private var width: CGFloat?
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    Text("All PDFs")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.leading)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height / 10, alignment: .leading)
                .background(Color(uiColor: UIColor.systemGray4))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        .padding([.leading, .top, .bottom])
                    TextField ("Search All Documents", text: $searchString)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                    Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        .padding(.trailing)
                }
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1))
                .padding([.leading, .top, .bottom])
                .frame(width: geo.size.width / 1.05 )
                
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach($searchString.wrappedValue == "" ? pdfsFetcher.pdfs :
                                pdfsFetcher.pdfs.filter({ pdf in
                        pdf.internalName.contains($searchString.wrappedValue.lowercased())
                    })
                            , id: \._id) { pdf in
                        
                        if let parsedString = pdf.file?.split(separator: "-") {
                            let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mylink/\(parsedString[1]).pdf")!)
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: WebView(request: request)
                                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(backButtonHidden)
                                            .navigationBarHidden(backButtonHidden)
                                            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                backButtonHidden.toggle()
                            })) {
                                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                    Image(systemName: "doc")
                                        .padding()
                                        .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                        .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { dimension in
                                            self.width = max(self.width ?? 0, dimension.width)
                                            return dimension[.leading]
                                        })
                                                            
                                    Text(pdf.internalName)
                                        .padding()
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                }
                                .padding(.leading)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
                .accentColor(Color.black)
                .onAppear{
                pdfsFetcher.pdfs == [] ? pdfsFetcher.fetchPDFs() : nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Pdf list and Seachbar]

Pdf list and Searchbar.

[image: Searchbar on focus]

The same view on Searchbar focus.

I would like the search string to filter the list of pdfs while maintaining the visibility of the list.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by making my @ObservableObject an @EnvironmentObject in my App :

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var pdfsFetcher = PDFsFetcher()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(pdfsFetcher)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct AllPdfListView: View { 
    @EnvironmentObject var pdfsFetcher: PDFsFetcher
}
```

Comment: Or you could probably just change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`